# Couting the letters of given word

Tags: c#

I am trying to count the letters of a given word. I stuck at the end. I do not know how to count the letters.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a word:");
        string kelime = Console.ReadLine();

        int numberofLetters = kelime.Length;

        Console.WriteLine("Your word has {0} characters", numberofLetters);

        for (int i = 0; i < numberofLetters; i++)
        {
            if
        }
    }
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "letters"? (There are all kinds of things you might consider.) Do you know about the indexer of strings, so you could use `char c = keline[i]`? Then consider whether or not that character is a letter...

Comment: for example: lets say word is "happy". Output will show that h:1, a:1,p:2, y:1

Comment: Ah, that's really unclear from the question. You should make the question clearer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store somewhere the letters you have processed and how many times you processed them. A good choice it would be a Dictionary, with key the letter and value the times you found this letter.

```
var lettersDictionary = new Dictionary<char, int>();
for (int i = 0; i < numberofLetters; i++)
{
    var currentLetter = kelime[i];
    if(lettersDictionary.ContainsKey(currentLetter))
    {
        // The dictionary contains the currentLetter. 
        // So we increase the times we found it by 1.
        lettersDictionary[currentLetter] += 1;
    }
    else
    {
        // The dictionary doesn't contain the currentLetter.
        // So we add the new key with the value of 1.
        lettersDictionary.Add(currentLetter,1);
    }
}
```

Having done the above you could build the output you want like below:

```
var keyValues = lettersDictionary.Keys.Select(key=>$"{key}: {lettersDictionary[key]}");
var output = string.Join(",", keyValues);
```